# HTML reduce gradient layer over image?

Tags: html, css

I have an image section with a gradient layer that was built into the stylesheet of the theme. What in this block of code do I need to change to reduce the gradient?

```
.image-section {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 80%, rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.2)), color-stop(30%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), color-stop(80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.9)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 30%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 30%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 30%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 30%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#33000000', endColorstr='#e6000000',GradientType=0 );
display: table;
overflow: hidden;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
```

Any help with handling this block of code is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like this block of code was generated using the [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), you may be able to import the relevant CSS there and make changes as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the gradient you should change the background gradient values for example :

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 80%, rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 100%);
```

The previous style it start with opacity 0.2 at 0% of the height and end with opacity 0.9 at 100% of the height, you can change those opacity values as you need.

let say that you want to start with 0.2 and end with 0.5, the style should be like this :

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 30%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%)
```

the style :

```
.image-section {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 80%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.2)), color-stop(30%,rgba(0,0,0,0.3)), color-stop(80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 30%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 30%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 30%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 30%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#33000000', endColorstr='#e6000000',GradientType=0 );
display: table;
overflow: hidden;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/rnjunkod/